# Mckee believed WAS the Mary Rose Vs Mackee believed TO BE the Mary Rose

Tags: complements

In 1967 , Edgerton's side-scan sonar systems revealed a large , unusually shaped object , which Mckee believed WAS the Mary Rose.

Shouldn't this be "Mackee believed TO BE the Mary Rose"?

Can somebody please explain the grammar?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is fine as written. This is the ordinary way of relativizing a constituent in a subordinate content clause:

```
          McKee believed  it   was the Mary Rose.
                           ↓
                         which
      .....................↓
      ↓
    which McKee believed  ____ was the Mary Rose
```

Note that a content clause with a relativized constituent is not introduced with the subordinator *that*.

Your paraphrase with infinitival *to be* is grammatical, but stilted.

Comment: Agree with everything in this answer except the last word. Stilted? Seems perfectly natural and normal to me. Slightly higher in register, but far from stilted.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=believed+it+to+be%2Cbelieved+it+is%2Cbelieved+that+it+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelieved%20it%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelieved%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelieved%20that%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0) shows *believed it to be* is more common that *believed (that) it is*, although neither is rare. I certainly wouldn't call it stilted.

Comment: @PeterShor Add *believed it was* to that NGram. ... I'll stand by the characterization. The infinitival is largely confined to the higher register, while the finite verb is at home in all registers; that strikes me as a pretty good operational definition of 'stilted'.